# Moment of Inertia around z axis

Tags: calculus

Hello I am having difficulty with the following;

I am wanting to find I, the moment of inertia about the z axis of the region that is bounded by the paraboloid $z=x^{2}+y^{2}$ and the $z=1$ plane, where the density is proportional to the distance from the z axis.

Here is what I have tried:

I thought maybe I could use the formula

$I= \iiint_{D}(x^2+y^2)\rho(x,y,z)dV$

and use that since $\rho(x,y,z)$ is proportional to distance from the $z$ axis, then for some constant $K$ we have $\rho(x,y,z)=K$(distance from z axis)

But I am not sure which distance from the z axis to use, or which formula to use.

Anyway, assuming the above is correct, then I would have

$I= \iiint_{D}K(x^2+y^2)(distance from z -axis)dV$

and the region D would be determined by knowing we are bound by the paraboloid and z=1 plane.

But I am stuck on it so far, can anyone please help me? Is it the correct approach? and how should I find distance to z axis? Maybe I don't need triple integrals? Anyways, I have tried my best to work on it, but I am not making any progress. I think if someone helped to explain then I could understand it for the future

Thank you

Update:

I am still working on this problem days after. I really wish I could just get some help so I can study it and move on!

Here is what else I have tried;

If we try cylindrical coordinates,

then $z=r^{2}$ and z goes to the plane ie $z =1$

\theta, would go from $0$ to $2pi$, and $r$ from $0$ to $1$

(however I still don't know how I could represent $K\rho $

but I would then have $\iiint_{D'} (r^3)(K(\rho))dzdrd\theta$
my only guess would be that K(\pho)=K(r)

giving $$K\iiint_{D'}r^{4}dzdrd\theta$$
But I don't know if so far it is the right approach? Please anyone?

Comment: If there is any reason why I am not getting any help please let me know so I can try to fix

Comment: First you find the center of mass from the origin and then you calculate the MMOI about the origin. lastly you use the parallel axis theorem to transfer the MMOI to the center of mass.

Comment: @PersonaA: I did solve the whole question for you, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work in cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$. The element of volume is $r\,dr\,d\theta\,dz$. The distance of a point to the $z$ axis is just $r$, and the density $\lambda r$. The paraboloid is $r^2=z$ or $r=\sqrt z$.

So the mass is

$$M=\int_{z=0}^1\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{\sqrt z}\lambda r\,r\,dr\,d\theta\,dz=\lambda2\pi\int_{z=0}^1\left.\frac{r^3}3\right|_0^{\sqrt z}dz=\lambda2\pi\left.\frac2{3\cdot5}z^{5/2}\right|_0^1=\lambda\frac{4\pi}{15}.$$

And the moment of inertia around $z$

$$I_{zz}=\int_{z=0}^1\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{\sqrt z}r^2\lambda r\,r\,dr\,d\theta\,dz=\lambda2\pi\int_{z=0}^1\left.\frac{r^5}5\right|_0^{\sqrt z}dz=\lambda2\pi\left.\frac2{5\cdot7}z^{7/2}\right|_0^1=\lambda\frac{4\pi}{35}.$$

Then

$$I_{zz}=\frac37M.$$